# Facebook Like button for fan page - cannot create simple button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, fan-page

is it possible to create simple Like button for fan page? When I create official Like button, insert my fan page URL in form, it always generate button with image and page title as it is Like box not Like button. I just want simple Like button only with "Like" label and users count.
Is this an issue or default behavior, or just my misunderstanding?
Thanks for advice
Tomas Teicher

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Did you mean you want this button?</strike>

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like

Alternatively, you may use AddThis widget - They even provide analytics for you.

http://www.addthis.com/

I use the widget on this website: http://muamalat.com.my/consumer-banking/financing/mortgage/

I must have misread your question. In that case I've only come across this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Uncheck show faces, stream and header; that's the cleanest you could get. Is this what you're looking for?

I don't think AddThis has that feature you speak of. :)

Comment: thanks for reply, yes, I mean thet Like button. When I use Add this. it just share current site on my profile. What I want to achieve, is permanent connection between facebook fan page and user who clicked on Like it button. Btw, is it possible to share content to fan page instead of profile, with Add this?

Comment: When I use Like button or Like box I cannot get rid of that image and title. So I think, there is not a solution, at least not with official facebook's buttons

Answer (score 0):

One way to only show the like button by itself is to hide the top part of the button by setting the `iframe` dimensions to the size of the button: 60x20.

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?&amp;href=&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=60&amp;height=20&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colosheme=light" 
 allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" 
 style="width: 60px; height: 20px;">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Iframe you need to place an http or https: because >iframe starts as

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href= ................></iframe>
```

and you need to place

```
<iframe src="**http:**//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href= ................></iframe>
```

The above answer did help me in finding that out.

Answer (score 0):

If i read this correct, then it is definitely possible:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Put in your Page URL, for example: https://www.facebook.com/bladauhu
(that is my own page)

Uncheck Send Button, use Layout Style "button_count", uncheck Show Faces. Leave the rest as it is and click on the "Get code" button. Use the HTML5 or XFBML Version.

For me, this works just like every other Website and it shows the correct number of likes from the Facebook Page. No additional Images, just the plain and simple Like button.

Answer (score 0):

Adding data-layout='button_count' to the HTML5 version worked for me:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://facebook.com/wewantoo" data-send="false" data-width="90" data-show-faces="false" data-layout='button_count'></div>
```