# Like Facebook Page button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

The default Facebook "[Like Box](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/)" is too big for my site.

I would like to use a very simple like button, without the facebook page picture, name, fan names, etc. When my website's visitors click on it, they should become fans of my Facebook page.

I can't find out how to remove the page name and picture (not sure if it's even possible)... Any idea?

--

update:

here is a very similar question: [Facebook Like button for fan page - cannot create simple button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590970/facebook-like-button-for-fan-page-cannot-create-simple-button) with no answer so far. Any workaround I could use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this more like it?
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
So your code would look something like this:
iFrame:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=212715052108961&amp;href=PAGEURL;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=50&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:50px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

XFBML:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=212715052108961&amp;xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="PAGEURL" send="false" layout="button_count" width="50" show_faces="false" font=""></fb:like>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a like [button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)?

Comment: Thanks... I don't know how I could miss this!!! It does exactly what I wanted, except that this time the button is a little small. But oh well...